# Split date range with time by day

Tags: python, algorithm, datetime

I have a range of dates over time.
Example:

```
diapason = ["2020-11-02 17:40", "2020-11-05 10:00"]
```

and I want to get such a split:

```
diapason = [(2020-11-02 17:40, 2020-11-03 00:00), (2020-11-03 00:00, 2020-11-04 00:00), (2020-11-04 00:00, 2020-11-05 00:00), (2020-11-05 00:00, 2020-11-05 10:00)]
```

How can i do this? So far, I only manage to divide by 24 hours something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
diapason = ["2020-11-02 17:40", "2020-11-05 10:00"]

start = datetime.strptime(diapason[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
end = datetime.strptime(diapason[1], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
r = [(start + timedelta(days=i)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f") for i in range(0, (end-start).days, 1)]

print(r)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. Is it that you want your intervals to be from midnight of one day to midnight the next day? (Plus the first and last intervals).
If that is the case, have you considered creating your `start` and `end` with `00:00` hours, do your for loop and then replace the first item of the first and last interval for your original `diapason[0]` and `diapason[1]` respectively. Basically you create the 24 hour periods from midnight to midnight and then you adjust the first and last periods.

Comment: yes, you understood my problem correctly, good idea, now I will try it

Comment: I was looking to do what the OP did first in his question, I think. So this `[pandas.date_range(start=datetime, periods=24, freq='H') for datetime in pandas.date_range(start=start_datetime, periods=2, freq='D')]` does it. The "last" `periods=2` can be adjusted then to generate as many days as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a date range with the elements being lists, replace first and last elements with start / end datetime and format to tuples of strings:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

diapason = ["2020-11-02 17:40", "2020-11-05 10:00"]
# diapason = ['2023-03-07 16:00:00','2023-03-14 19:00:00']

start, end = [datetime.fromisoformat(d) for d in diapason]
offset = 1 if start.time() <= end.time() else 2

output = [
    [start.date() + timedelta(d), start.date() + timedelta(d + 1)]
    for d in range((end - start).days + offset)
]

output[0][0], output[-1][-1] = start, end

output = [
    (l[0].strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"), l[1].strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")) for l in output
]

# output
# [('2020-11-02 17:40', '2020-11-03 00:00'),
#  ('2020-11-03 00:00', '2020-11-04 00:00'),
#  ('2020-11-04 00:00', '2020-11-05 00:00'),
#  ('2020-11-05 00:00', '2020-11-05 10:00')]
```

Comment: This works great when start time hour is less than the end time hour, it works for start_time='2023-03-07 16:00:00' and end_time='2023-03-14 15:00:00', but in case of start_time='2023-03-07 16:00:00 and end_time='2023-03-14 19:00:00' the results are wrong

Comment: @AmirReza thanks for pointing this out. I have made and edit. Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

First generate all the possible dates and add start and end timestamps. Sort them and finally iterate to get all the possible couples od timestamps.
Here an example:

```
diapason = ["2020-11-02 17:40", "2020-11-05 10:00"]
start = datetime.strptime(diapason[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
end = datetime.strptime(diapason[-1], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

dates = [datetime.strptime(str(date), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") for date in pd.date_range(start.date() + timedelta(1), end.date())] + [start, end]
dates = sorted(dates)

diapason = []
for i in range(len(dates)-1):
    diapason.append((dates[i], dates[i+1]))
```

Which gives you:

```
[(datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 2, 17, 40), datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 3, 0, 0)),
 (datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 3, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 4, 0, 0)),
 (datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 5, 0, 0)),
 (datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 5, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 5, 10, 0))]
```

You can then cast them as strings or reformat them if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
diapason = ["2020-11-02 17:40", "2020-11-05 10:00"]

start = datetime.strptime(diapason[0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
end = datetime.strptime(diapason[1], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

def d(date): return timedelta(hours=date.hour, minutes=date.minute, seconds=date.second)

r = [(start - d(start) + timedelta(days=i)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f") for i in range(1, (end-start).days + 2)]
r = r + diapason
r.sort()
print(r)
```

which gives you

```
['2020-11-02 17:40',
 '2020-11-03 00:00:00.000000',
 '2020-11-04 00:00:00.000000',
 '2020-11-05 00:00:00.000000',
 '2020-11-05 10:00']
```